# How to link OpenCV 4 with ROS (cv_bridge)

Tags: opencv, ros

I'm using OpenCV in ROS Melodic, I need now to use cv::dnn (deep neural network), which is incluced in OpenCV 4, which I have installed, and set it to my CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED )
```

this is warning that I'm getting when I do command: **catkin_make** in my ros workspace:

> /usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.2, needed by
>   /opt/ros/melodic/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with
>   libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1

I ignored that but I can't rosrun any node with opencv right now.

Can someone help me how to set OpenCV 4 in cv_bridge (ROS melodic system)?

Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
Jovan.

Answer (score 3):

There is an opencv shipped with ROS which is used for image related stuff. Some ROS packages such as cv_bridge, image_geometry etc. use this opencv by default. This is the reason you get segmentation fault because different opencv versions are storing image in different formats.

If you want to use a custom opencv within your node, you must include these packages in your working directory and compile them also. For example, you must include [cv_bridge source code](https://github.com/strawlab/vision_opencv/tree/master/cv_bridge) in your node's cmakelist.

Comment: I understand, but can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: Clone cv_bridge inside catkin workspace source folder, when compiling it with catkin_make, specify your own opencv's directory:   -DOpenCV_DIR=PATH_TO_YOUR_OPENCV  . Like this:  catkin_make --cmake-args -DOpenCV_DIR=PATH_TO_OPENCV

Comment: Then when including cv_bridge in your ROS node (from node's cmakelists.txt), specify your compiled cv_bridge so it doesn't use the default one.

Comment: But how your node gets image input? From sensor? From another node? From network/filesystem? Some other ros packages may need to be compiled depending on that. There is a complete answer that removes all opencv stuff from ROS and rebuild them again in here: https://answers.opencv.org/question/211349/how-to-linked-opencv-345-dnn-module-with-custom-cv_bridge-using-catkin-error-undefined-reference-cvdnnexperimental_dnn_v2netnet/ , but I think just recompiling some specific packages should be enough.

Comment: My node gets image from another node via cv_bridge.
How to specify my compiled cv_bridge in node's CMakeLists.txt?
Also, which path should I use to OpenCV when I use catkin_make in workspace?
When I installed (built) OpenCV4 with cmake command, I used preffix CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local.

Comment: If image message is coming from another node, you should probably use the solution I linked (completely replacing ros-opencv and opencv related packages). Because that node is also going to use its own image format and so on...

Comment: I didn't find anything helpful in this link.
If you mean on comment from Eduardo there's solution similar like yours, but I didn't find answer for my questions from earlier post.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to download a suitable version of vision_opencv from https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/releases. Then extract the contents (containing some packages `cv_bridge` `image_geometry` `opencv_tests` `vision_opencv`) to a folder called `vision_opencv` of your `src` folder in your catkin workspace.

Now `catkin_make` or `catkin build` your workspace and the necessary ros opencv packages will compile and link against the local `vision_opencv` folder. You might need to clean your workspace before that.